# Regular expression only replacing last occurrence in string

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to replace the `src` attribute of each image in the following HTML:

```
var html = @"<img height=49 src=""Image25.gif"" width=94> or <img height=44 src=""Image26.gif"" width=117> or <img height=41 src=""Image27.gif"" width=46>";

Console.WriteLine( Regex.Replace( html,
                                  @"(<img.*src="")(.*"".*>)",
                                  m => m.Groups[1] + "/File/Download/" + m.Groups[2],
                                  RegexOptions.IgnoreCase ) );
```

The output of which is:

```
<img height=49 src="Image25.gif" width=94> or <img height=44 src="Image26.gif" width=117> or <img height=41 src="/File/Download/Image27.gif" width=46>
```

The output should be:

```
<img height=49 src="/File/Download/Image25.gif" width=94> or <img height=44 src="/File/Download/Image26.gif" width=117> or <img height=41 src="/File/Download/Image27.gif" width=46>
```

Can you do multiple replacements on a single line like this with C#?

Comment: Your problem lies in the `<img.*`. It is making the match go to the end of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `*?` lazy [quantifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3206d374%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Replace(html,
    @"(<img.*?src="")(.*?"".*?>)",
    m => m.Groups[1] + "/File/Download/" + m.Groups[2],
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase));
```